# How to skip 4-byte unicode word in a sentence

Tags: python, unicode, warnings

There is a Warning when inserting 4-byte unicode to mysql(utf8).
I want to skip the 4-byte unicode word if it exist in a sentence.
So that it can insert to mysql successfully. :D


For example. '\xf0\x9f\x8e\x81' is a gift icon. 
The sentence is 'This  is great.'
And it can process like this. 'This is great.'


Thank you very much !!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the string in Unicode form initially, you can remove characters from outside the Basic-Multilingual-Plane characters by doing:

```
if len(u'\U00010000') == 1:
    s = re.sub(u'[\U00010000-\U001FFFFF]', u'', s)
else:
    s = re.sub(u'[\uD800-\uDFFF]', u'', s)
```

(the two branches are necessary to cater for Python ‘narrow builds’, like the standard Windows build of Python 2, where strings store non-BMP characters using UTF-16 surrogate code units. If you are using a recent Python 3 then you can skip this as all builds are now ‘wide’.)

But in any case you would be much better off configuring your tables to store data using the `utf8mb4` encoding, which represents “real” UTF-8 including the four-byte characters, rather than MySQL's limited `utf8`.

Comment: Hi~~ thanks for your reply ^_^.
If I have a variable named 'Test'. Its value is 'This  is great.' How can I use in your way?? :D

Comment: substitute `Test` for `s` in the above.

Comment: I named a variable called 's' and let s = 'This  is great.' And then put your code. At the last, I print s. And it show the error message. "Unicode Error 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes"